# Angular relationship of tables from many to many

Tags: django, angular

I have a problem in angular i dont now how to call from the table to an object that has many to many relationship
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "test",
        "email": "test1@gmail.com",
        "groups": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Empleados",
                "permissions": []
            }
        ]
    },
]

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of users;">
              <td>{{item.id}}</td>
              <td>{{item.username}}</td>
              <td>{{item.email}}</td>
              <td>{{item.groups.name}}</td>
              <td>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Leer</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn btn-warning">Editar</a>
                  <button class="delete" (click)="Eliminar(item)">Eliminar</button>
              </td>
          </tr>
```

that does not work for me, it only works for me when the relationship is one to many

try to do this, I only work the first column

{{item.groups[0].name}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest `*ngFor` statements by iterating over e.g. an array property of in your case the `item` variable:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of users;">
    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
    <td>{{item.username}}</td>
    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
    <td>{{item.groups.name}}</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <!-- e.g. here do: -->
    <td>
        <table border="0">
            <tr *ngFor="let group of item.groups>
                <td>{{ group.name }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```